# Jackson deserialization classes that can be different types from XSD choice

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization, jsonparser

I have the following Deserializer:

```
@Override
  public PrivateInstance deserialize(
      final JsonParser jsonParser,
      final DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
      throws IOException
  {
    ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jsonParser.getCodec();
    ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(jsonParser);

    Class<? extends PrivateInstance> instanceClass;

    if (true) {
      instanceClass = ABCEntity.class;
    } else {
      instanceClass = XYZEntity.class;
    }
    if (instanceClass == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return mapper.readValue((DataInput) root, instanceClass);
  }
}
```

My idea is to deserialize XML content where the schema definition has **choice** so it can be really one, but at the moment of deserializing I have no idea which one it is but I want to return the right one

I need to return either of those objects depending on what's being parsed, I've been trying to find the best way but nothing works, how can I know what the object being parsed is an instance of?

Comment: You pass the class you want to deserialize as parameter. Why don't you just use one of the many available JSON parsers? Is this for learning purposes?

Comment: yes, I am exploring more of Jackson, the class pass as a parameter is the Type PrivateInstance but it could be really ABCEntity or XYZEntity ( both extend PrivateInstance) present in the Jackson, so I would like to have the right object, and both classes are really different, the parent only has the @JsonDeserialize annotation

Comment: You need to pass the correct class you want to deserialize. There's no way the parser knows which subclass class you want from the JSON. Or you need to include this information in the JSON itself.

Comment: Basically I am trying to deserialized a XML where the spec has <choice> so it can be really only one, I was trying this approach of a parent component, but maybe it's not a good idea

Comment: Is the parent class abstract?

Comment: You may start begin with one class, if you get an JsonParseException then try the other class.

Comment: yes, the parent class is abstract